Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2024-04-25T14:32:42 of type java.time.format.Parsed
I've below java program which converts string to Instant object.

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class JenkinsBuildDateFormatApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String extractedDate = "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a");
        TemporalAccessor ta = dtf.parse(extractedDate);
        System.out.println(Instant.from(ta));
    }
}

When I run the program, I get below error -
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: > {},ISO resolved to 2024-04-25T14:32:42 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:381)
    at JenkinsBuildDateFormatApp.main(JenkinsBuildDateFormatApp.java:12)
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:215)
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:376)
    ... 1 more
Process finished with exit code 1

How can I resolve the error?

"Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" is not enough information to get an Instant. "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" in China would be a different instant from "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" in the UK.

@Sweeper what should I provide to make this work?

(I thought it would be obvious to tell from my previous comment...) You need a ZoneId. What timezone is "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" in? If you don't have a timezone, you can parse it to a LocalDateTime instead.

Note that given string is also locale-dependent, e.g. will not work for Germany or UK since these use different representation for months. Better also provide the Locale, for example: var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a", Locale.US); var local = LocalDateTime.parse(extractedDate, formatter); (unless the default is also used to create  the string)

There are at least two options. (1) First set the time zone on the formatter, for example DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a", Locale.ROOT).withZone(ZoneId.of("Indian/Maldives")). Then parse into an Instant using dtf.parse(extractedDate, Instant::from). Gives 2024-04-25T09:32:42Z. (2) Parse into a LocalDateTime as mentioned and shown. Convert to Instant using local.atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pohnpei")).toInstant(). Gives 2024-04-25T03:32:42Z. In either case substitute your desired time zone. Perhaps ZoneId.systemDefault()?

It’s nice that the question is so clear about expected and observed behaviour. You might have told us what your search turned up since there are similar questions out there, though I didn’t find an exact duplicate. I find it a good question, also one that is likely to help future readers. No doubt someone else will have the same or a similar problem. +1

@Sweeper: ... would be a different instant from "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" in the UK Actually that's not a UK format, but it would be a US one. UK would be Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 pm. That's why it's important to set the Locale on the formatter as @user85421 mentioned

I'm posting this to show the essence of the above comments, which are almost entirely correct:
import java.util.Locale;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class JenkinsBuildDateFormatApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String extractedDate = "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a");
        // Above question comments already show why it's necessary
        // to give the Formatter these two attributes for the rest of the
        // code to work (not that this is how one would necessarily *actually write* it)
        dtf = dtf.withLocale(Locale.US).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        TemporalAccessor ta = dtf.parse(extractedDate);
        System.out.println(Instant.from(ta));
    }
}


tl;dr
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM" , 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu, h:m:s a") 
    .withLocale( Locale.US )  
)
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )  // Specify the unspoken time zone you know to have been intended for this input. 
)
.toInstant()  // Adjust from the intended time zone to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

Details
The Answer by g00se is correct. But the approach in your code is misguided.
Avoid TemporalAccessor
Firstly, you are misusing the java.time framework. As the Javadoc indicates, TemporalAccessor is meant for use within the framework, not by app developers. To quote:

Framework-level interface …
This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. …

Date, time
Instead, deal with your input text head-on. What you have is a date with a time-of-day. So you should parse as a LocalDateTime object.
Unfortunately, that input text is in a localized format. I recommend you educate the publisher of your data about exchanging date-time values textually only in the standard formats defined in ISO 8601. In the mean time, define a custom formatting pattern to match.
Be aware that elements of your input depend on a particular human language and cultural norms. That means a Locale is involved. Specify the appropriate Locale explicitly. If omitted, the runtime JVM’s current default locale will be implicitly applied.
By the way, your example input is not entirely helpful. We cannot tell if the minute and second will use a padding zero for single digit values. Ditto for day-of-month. Think that through when posting such data, and when documenting in your own code.
String input = "Apr 25, 2024, 2:32:42 PM"; ;
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:m:s a") 
        .withLocale( locale ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;

Date, time, and offset/zone
Apparently you want an Instant object. That class represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. The contents include a date, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
But your LocalDateTime and string input have only two of those three parts. They lack the context of an offset or a time zone. So, you cannot determine a Instant from a LocalDateTime alone.
You apparently believe that your date-with-time input was intended to represent a moment as seen in a particular time zone. Well, ideally, that zone information should have been included with the string input.
Omitting the zone from a date-with-time is like omitting the currency indicator from an amount of money. You can assume the intended currency was Canadian Dollar, but you cannot know for certain that is not the Euro. Such inputs should have included a standardized currency indicator such as CAD or EUR.
Likewise, we can assume the intended time zone, but doing so is  risky business. I would strongly recommend you instead fix your data inputs. But if you insist on proceeding…
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;

Now we have a moment, a point on the timeline, in our ZonedDateTime. This moment is viewed from the wall-clock/calendar in use by someone in Japan in the Asia/Tokyo time zone.
You can extract a Instant from that ZonedDateTime object. You will be effectively adjusting the date and time to an offset of UTC of zero, the definition of a Instant object.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;

